# Can't login to admin panel opencart

Tags: opencart

I can't login to admin panel,if i use link like - http://www.devagniy.ru/admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=17c11d6d8897be10034cfefef4f190c5. browser hangs,and than nginx timeout error.

But if i change link to - http://www.devagniy.ru/admin/index.php?route=catalog/category&token=b41ec65bd4290b1aad38e6152a259ab0 (**route=catalog/category**),i login imidiatly.

Opencart on nginx(can show config) and site work, if somebody know, what is the problem?

I would be glad of any promp.

Comment: Have you installed any module so far? I can see you are using v1.5.5.1.2 which is rather old, try installing v1.5.6.4

Comment: Yes, i install vqmode and Export/Import Tool. Thanks for advise, try to install new version.

Comment: There might be a problem with the modules, try to see if the login works without any modules installed ... I've noticed that most of the OC modules are buggy.

Comment: No. It seems like in server eviroment something wrong. Install blank shop on another domen and get the same problem(.

Comment: Install 1.5.6.4, and now main admin page opens, but very slowly. On emty base).It seems that open cart do very havy operations on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any module on Dashboard which is related to showing sales reports or graphs? If so, it may have heavy queries or bad written code which is causing the page to load slow.